# Improve quality (i.e. anti-aliasing of the lines) of contourf in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some function in 2D which returns integer values. Unfortunately, the corresponding contourf plot does not have a good quality (i.e. anti-aliasing of the lines) unless I increase the fineness a lot. Any suggestions?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def some_non_accessible_function(X,Y):
    return np.round(2*X**3 - 3*Y**3)


Nx = Ny = 50
X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-1,1,Nx),np.linspace(-1,1,Ny),indexing= "ij")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

im = ax.contourf(X,Y,some_non_accessible_function(X,Y),levels=range(-6,6))
plt.colorbar(im)
ax.set_title("N = 100")
plt.savefig("./plot1.pdf")

plt.show()
```

[image: good_quality][image: bad_quality]

Comment: If the function *does* return integer values, than the "stepped" contour lines ***are*** actually a correct representation of the data. If the function does not necessarily return integers, then increasing the grid density is a viable solution.

Comment: Good point. I wonder if it was possible to do have some interpolated lines in between to increase the quality without increasing the fineness? I hoped there was an matplotlib command for that.

Comment: You can smooth the array before sending to contour.